# Finding out the parent of clicked element in android ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm building my first app based on material from http://javatechig.com/video/json-feed-reader-in-android.
Everything goes ok so far, but I found one bug with ListView elements, which I can not manage to resolve by myself :(
I have extended list_row_layout.xml by 2 fields:

```
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:text="komcie"
    android:textSize="11sp"
    android:id="@+id/loadComments"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:background="#bbb"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="clickedLoadComments"
    android:elegantTextHeight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbImage"
    android:layout_below="@+id/content"
    android:padding="1px" />    

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/comment_list"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbImage"
    android:layout_below="@+id/content"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector_flatcolor"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Button.android:onClick="clickedLoadComments" function load Json with elements into ListView/comment_list. It works quite fine. But if there are more elements than could be displayed on screen (~8 elements) there is a bug. **Comments from clicked element are loaded into every 8th element in a ListView.**
Some code:

```
    public void clickedLoadComments(View v)
{
    try {
        View parent = (View)v.getParent();
        ViewHolder t = (ViewHolder) parent.getTag();

        if( parent != null ) {
            this.loadCommentsForLeaf(parent);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}   

protected void loadCommentsForLeaf( View view )
{
    String tmpUrl = "http://some.url.com/Ajax/LoadComments?lid=" + this.currentLeafInUse;


    JSONObject commentsJson = this.getJSONFromUrl(tmpUrl);
    this.parseJsonComments(commentsJson);

    if( commentsJson != null )
        this.updateCommentList(view);
}   

public void updateCommentList( View view) {
    commentListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.comment_list);
    commentListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

CommentListAdapter cla = new CommentListAdapter(this, this.commentList.get(this.currentLeafInUse));
    commentListView.setAdapter(cla);



        // Set list height.
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = commentListView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(commentListView) + 20;
    commentListView.setLayoutParams(params);
    commentListView.requestLayout();

}
```

CustomListAdapter.java code is mostly the same as the one in tutorial.

I would really appreciate help as I have spent many hours figuring it out with not success :(

Comment: @AndreuRodrígueziDonaire: "Comments from clicked element are loaded into every 8th element in a ListView."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a guess. You might post your Adapter code and your `parseJsonComments` also if this does not work.

**The Cause:**

The problem you are describing might be caused due to the recycling and the reusage of Views. Take a look at this image from [http://android.amberfog.com](http://android.amberfog.com/)

[image]

As you can see the 1. items is reused and becomes the 8. item after scrolling.

Let's assume that Item 1 has an `OnClickListener` which updates a Text of the item. 
For example we set the text to "clicked" after the `OnClickListener` is triggered.

Because item 1 is reused to create item 8, item 8 will also display the text "clicked".

**The Solution:**

The usual way is to save all states/content in a List(or whatever) and update everything in the getView call. So if you want to update text:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    ...
    holder.textView.setText(jsonTexts[position]);
    ...

    return convertView;
}
```

And if you want to update an item just update the List in your Adapter which holds the content/JsonObjects(etc.) and call `notifyDataSetChanged`.

```
public void updateCommentList(JSONObject commentsJson, int position) {
     // does not exist you might create something 
     //like that in your Adapter class
     commentListAdapter.updateItem(commentsJson,position); 
     commentListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: So as I thought. You have to render whole list again, can not change just one element. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is also possible to update just one View. My provided answer is just a simple and clean solution.

Comment: To update just one view. You have to make sure you update the right view and you have to make sure the view is properly recreated in the getView method.

Comment: In my solution this might be simply done by removing the commentListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); line and updating the View and the content List in updateItem. But this might be a little tricky when you are updating async like in the other question.

Comment: So there is room for improvements. You may also take a look at RecyclerView which is able to update one item by default.

Answer (score 0):

After i populate the listview i call this method:

```
private void registerClickCallback() {
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,
                int position, long id) {
            String xx = position+ ":" + id;

            //then you can do what ever you want

        }

    });
}
```