# Randomly refreshing thumb in android ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, thumbnails

I'm building my first app based on material from http://javatechig.com/video/json-feed-reader-in-android. 
Everything goes quite ok so far, but there is a bug in thumbnails. When I scroll list, random thumb images quick "refresh" with random different thumb and back to original one. Any suggestion why it behaves like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the following page:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

The part *Handle Concurrency* explains everything:

> Common view components such as ListView and GridView introduce another
>   issue when used in conjunction with the AsyncTask as demonstrated in
>   the previous section. In order to be efficient with memory, these
>   components recycle child views as the user scrolls. If each child view
>   triggers an AsyncTask, there is no guarantee that when it completes,
>   the associated view has not already been recycled for use in another
>   child view. Furthermore, there is no guarantee that the order in which
>   asynchronous tasks are started is the order that they complete.

So you are right. This is actually a bug of this sample which hasn't got a proper load/display logic.

Comment: That helps me better understand cycling of elements.
Now, I guess this is connected to my another issue with ListView.
I will be grateful if You could look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308881/finding-out-the-parent-of-clicked-element-in-android-listview


Thanks a lot!